# Find isomorphic groups given a Cayley table with four elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm given the following Cayley table

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\cdot & e & a & b & c \\ \hline
 e & e & a & b & c  \\ \hline
 a & a & e & c & b \\ \hline
 b & b & c & a & e \\ \hline
 c & c & b & e & a \\ \hline
\end{array}

Having the obvious properties:
$$ a^2=e, bc=e, ba=c, ac=b, b^2=a,c^2=a$$

The task is to find symmetry groups which meet the requirements by the table.
One possible isomorph is $C_4$.

Now $C_4$ has a 4-fould rotational axis which is obvious (I was told) from $b^4=b^2 b^2=a a = e$ or $c^4=c^2 c^2=a a =e$

Even though I completely lack intuition here it looks correct because repeating operation $b$ 4 times in a row doesn't change anything.

But why exactly does this tell me that this rotation is 4-fold?

Then I was told that  $b\cdot c=(a\cdot c)\cdot c=e$ implies a possible 3-fold rotational axis. 
This is something I just can't wrap my mind around.

I hope somebody can give me a bit of intuition about this.

ANSWER: Assumption is wrong! there is no way to find an isomorphic symmetry-group having a three-fold rotational axis here. I was misinformed.

ANSWER PART2: The 4-fold rotational axis is implied by $b^4=e$ because only a rotation by 90° repeated 4 times in a row can result in the original state.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** There are two isomorphism classes for groups of order four, given by the representatives $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$. One of them has an element of order $4$; the other does not. Think about the element $b$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Shouldn't it be possible to deduce the order of rotational symmetries only by looking at the table wihtout knowing what $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_2$ are?

Comment: You're welcome, @ODIUM. It depends on what your definitions are but, yes, in principle, one should be able to.

Comment: Then again, who said that rotational symmetries should be a part of the picture? Group theory in general is much broader than that.

Answer (score 0):

If we swap colums $a$ and $b$...

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\cdot & e & b & a & c \\ \hline
 e & e & b & a & c  \\ \hline
 b & b & a & c & e \\ \hline
 a & a & c & e & b \\ \hline
 c & c & e & b & a \\ \hline
\end{array}$

It is more obviously a cyclic group.

But as Shaun points out, there are only two classes of groups of order 4.  It must be one or the other.